# Threejs Frame Drop on camera move backwards

Tags: reactjs, scroll, three.js, 3d

I'm built a threejs project which is a very long tunnel (made of smaller ones).

- there are a lot of textures because each of the tunnel needs to have a different texture map and color.
- the camera moves on scroll

It's a huge project but I'm managing to keep a frame rate at 60.

My problem is:

- the animation frame drops considerable when the tunnel is scrolled backwards
- this only happens on scroll backwards or when the camera Z position is brought to a lower value (for example, this also happens when I change the camera Z position to a lower value with this.camera.set - see the button 'Backwards' on the sandbox)
- when the camera Z position is brought to a lower value, the frame drops, but then goes up again by scrolling forwards

I can't figure out why the animation lags only on scroll backwards / when the camera Z position is brought to a lower value.

I'm guessing that maybe there is something wrong with the way I'm handling the rendering loop?

Would appreciate any feedback or ideas!

here is the sandbox (view it on CHROME):
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sutherland-eijf0?file=/src/App.js